# Missing content-encoding in Response Header for Request headers with accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br (in that precise order) for HTTPS Requests

Tags: httprequest, websphere-portal, http-response-codes, brotli

We are using IBM Portal (version 8.0.0.xx??). We have 2 IBM portal servers sitting behind 2 Apache http servers.
In one of our portlets, we have a jsp file that includes the following resources:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/include/css/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/include/css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/include/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/include/css/include.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/include/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/include/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

When using the latest versions of Chrome and FF, in all cases, the https request header has the following token: `Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br`

When the https response comes back from the server, the following resources ***do not come back with a content-encoding token in the response header*** (i.e `content-encoding:gzip`)

- jquery-ui.structure.min.css
- jquery-ui.theme.min.css
- include.css

So the response body then shows compressed content since the browser, or receiving entity, assumes the resource has not been compressed and therefore does not apply any uncompression. The resulting content is then ofcourse rendered as garbled text. This is due to the absence of the `content-encoding: gzip` response header token.

Strangely, the other resources:

- jquery-ui.min.css
- jquery-1.11.1.min.js
- jquery-ui.min.js

  ***All come back with a correct*** `content-encoding: gzip` token for secure requests and the response is uncompressed correctly.

All http requests return back fine, its only the https requests that fail for some resources.

### What I've done to diagnose:

- I’ve hit each portal server directly and there are no problems for
  both secure and unsecure requests. Even though the browser sends an
  accept-encoding header, the servers both respond with no
  content-encoding response which means that they are likely not doing
  any compression (I'm guessing?)
- I’ve hit each http server that sit in front of the portal servers directly, and both servers ***show the problems for https as I've described above***.
- I’ve sent https requests inside and outside the browser sending requests and playing around with the accept-encoding header:
- `Accept-encoding: gzip`                              **works**
- `Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate`                     **works**
- `Accept-encoding: gzip, br, deflate`                 **works**
- `Accept-encoding: br, deflate, gzip`                 **works**
- `Accept-encoding: deflate, br, gzip`                 **works**
- `Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br`                 ***doesn’t work***
- I’ve downgraded my version of Chrome to version 57 and I can see that the accept-encoding header for https was: `gzip, deflate, br, sdch` which works. Switching back to the latest version, the accept-encoding header for https changes to : `gzip, deflate, br`, which fails. It seems Google used to use the SDCH data compression algorithm for all requests. Anything different from ‘`gzip, deflate, br`’ works!
- SDCH compression was removed from Google Chrome, and other Chromium
  products, in version 59.3. As soon as you go to ‘About Chrome’, the
  version auto updates to version 64 which Google Chrome enforces by
  default.  Since sdch is removed, it leaves the offending
  accept-encoding of ‘`gzip, deflate, br`’ which fails.
- FF has the same problem as Chrome. When I inspected the
  accept-encoding for http/https, it is the same as Chrome:
- For http requests: accept-encoding: `gzip, deflate`
- For https requests: accept-encoding: `gzip, deflate, br` (br is only
  for https)
- However, FF allowed me to change the accept-encoding and if I change
  the order for https, to anything else i.e) `gzip, br, deflate`, ***IT
  WORKS!***
- Also, this all works in IE, because when I inspected the
  accept-encoding for https requests, it is ‘gzip, deflate’.  The ‘br’ (brotli compression) token is missing and hence it works.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. It’s not clear to me what is doing the compression and failing to send the correct content encoding. Is it Apache or IBM Portal?

Comment: Hi @BarryPollard, thanks for the response. it appears the compression is happening on the Apache side since hitting the portal servers directly returns the resources fine. Moreover, the responses coming back from hitting the portal directly do not return a content-encoding response header.

Comment: Can you show the response headers or a good request and a bad request? Can you show the Apache compression settings (SetOutputFilter, AddOutputFilterByType...etc)?

Comment: Really need to see verbatim response headers on a pair of requests to even begin.  My guess is a poisoned or buggy cache.

Comment: @covener, indeed, the problem was poisoned cache. All of the portlet/applications within our httpd.conf file had a CacheDisable directive except for the particular portlet that was exhibiting the errors. After including that portlet and restarting apache, the resource was fine. My guess is that when Chrome/FF were updated with the new AE values of gzip, deflate, br it somehow cached a compressed copy indefinitely.  Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as suspected by @covener, was poisoned cache. All of the portlet/applications within our httpd.conf file had a CacheDisable directive except for the particular portlet that was exhibiting the errors. After including that portlet and restarting apache, the resources all came back with a proper content-encoding response header and subsequently decompressed fine. 
Thanks for all the help guys.